# To check whether the day belongs to EDT or EST in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to check whether the present time belongs to EDT or EST.

```
For Example:

1.9.3-p545 :020 > Time.now.in_time_zone
=> Wed, 02 Jul 2014 10:22:46 UTC +00:00
```

To know whether the above time comes in  EDT/EST

Comment: I guess this `Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")` would do.

Comment: Time.now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').dst? did the trick. Thanks @Pavan

Answer (score 3):

`Time.zone` will give you the timezone. On my computer, right now:

```
irb(main):014:0> Time.now.zone
=> "EDT"
```

If you simply want to know whether daylight savings time is in effect, `Time.dst?` will give you that information:

```
irb(main):015:0> Time.now.dst?
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this using the [`dst?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-dst-3F) method of `TimeWithZone` class.

Example:

```
Time.zone.now.dst?
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the zone by using zone() method and compare with EDT or EST. It returns the TimeZone for the current request, if this has been set (via #zone=). If zone has not been set for the current request, returns the TimeZone specified in config.time_zone.

```
Time.now.in_time_zone.zone
```